# histogram: setting y-axis label for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have dataframe:

```
d = {'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'], 
     'value': [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
     'count': [4, 3, 7, 3, 12, 14, 5, 10, 3, 8, 7, 15, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I want to plot multiple histograms in one figure. That is, a histogram for group A, a histogram for group B and group D in one figure. So, labels is a `group` column, y-axis is `count`, x-axis is `value`.

I do this, but there are incorrect values on the y-axis and it builds several figures.

```
axarr = df.hist(column='value', by = 'group', bins = 20)

for ax in axarr.flatten():
    ax.set_xlabel("value")
    ax.set_ylabel("count")
```

Comment: To clarify, is it possible that you are looking for bar plots? Histogram plots usually work with BINs (ranges) and the frequency (count) within those, and from the looks of your `df` that would have been kinda already included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking for a grouped bar plot (pending the clarification in the comments):

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'], 
     'value': [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
     'count': [4, 3, 7, 3, 12, 14, 5, 10, 3, 8, 7, 15, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    values="count",
    index="value",
    columns="group",
)

ax = df_pivot.plot(kind="bar")
fig = ax.get_figure()                
fig.set_size_inches(7, 6)
ax.set_xlabel("value")
ax.set_ylabel("count")
```

Brief plot option:

```
pd.pivot(df, index="value", columns="group").plot(kind="bar", y='count')
```

**Brief explanation:**

Pivot table for preparation:

- x-axis 'value' as index
- different bars 'group' as columns

```
group    A     B     D
value                 
0.2    4.0  12.0   3.0
0.4    3.0  14.0   8.0
0.6    7.0   5.0   7.0
0.8    3.0  10.0  15.0
1.0    NaN   NaN   4.0
```

Pandas [`.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) can handle that groupded bar plot directly after the df_pivot preparation.
Its default backend is matplotlib, so usual commands apply (like `fig.savefig`).

---

**Add-on apperance:**

You can make it look more like a hist plot concerning the x-axis by aligning the spacing in between the groups:

[image]

Just add a `, width=0.95` (or =1.0) within the `.plot(   )` statements.

Comment: I can't achieve the same result using the hist function?

Comment: @Rory if achieving that with hist for your dataset it would probably need a makeshift. By default you state the number of intended BINs and the ranges within the x-axis values are then calculated under the hood. I think you can supply the BINs instead of letting them being calulated, but to get that going it's a major band-aid. To add: That's mainly related to the data you have. There are indeed dataset where such a plot with hist is the feasible one.

Comment: @Rory check the add-on, maybe that appearance is what you are looking for when asking for a hist plot.